# AttributeError: 'Results' object has no attribute 'box'. can anyone explain this?

Tags: python, opencv, detection, yolov8

```
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\yolov8parkingspace-main\yolov8parkingspace-main\testcount.py", line 62, in <module>
    a=results[0].box.box
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 156, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"'{name}' object has no attribute '{attr}'. See valid attributes below.\n{self.__doc__}")
AttributeError: 'Results' object has no attribute 'box'. See valid attributes below.
```

this was the error, i don't know how to solve this cause im new at programming. thanks

im trying to make a parking spot detection using yolo v8 with python.

Comment: You haven't given enough details for those who may want to help you. (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: The error message is clear -- you are trying to access the `.box` attribute of an object, that does not have any such attribute.